# Swift 2 - Uber-like location picker with MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, location, mkmapview, core-location

I'm trying to make an uber-like location picker from a small MKMapView in my class. My problem is the following :

Since I want to have the initial region to be centered at the user current location, I set the initial region inside the location manager function like this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (locations.last?.coordinate)!
            let latDelta = 0.005
            let lonDelta = 0.005
            let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelta, longitudeDelta: lonDelta)
            let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locValue, span)
            self.locationMap.setRegion(region, animated: false)
           }
```

The problem with this is that every time that the user tries to drag the map region to pick a location, obviously since the location is being always updated and the function is being called at everytime the location is updates, the map region goes back to its initial point as the function above states.

Another thing is that if I try to extract the locValue variable and assign it to a instance variable of the class within the function adding a line like this :

```
self.userLocation = locValue
```

self.userLocation won't change. If you have any suggestion on how to get a single location without updating it or how to fix either one of these problems it would be really appreciated if you could let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to stop ``CLLocationManager`` after ``setRegion()``, like ``manager.stopUpdatingLocation()``?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually works. However, at the beginning it does center the region at the user's exact location, it's a little off. Do you know why? Is it because it needs some time to get an accurate location? In that case, is there a way I can stop updating the location after I got a good user's location?

Comment: Yeah, you are right about it. It needs some time depends on different accuracy. If you look at ``CLLocation``, there is a property ``timestamp``. You can use it to set a gap and obtain a potential better location; then stop manager at that moment.

Comment: May be this is too late for OP, but this tutorial  [ http://shrikar.com/build-your-own-uber-app-in-swift/ ] might help anyone try to do the same thing as the OP.